# typo3: how to find the page which has certain flexform setting?

Tags: typo3

```
$func = $this->pi_getFFvalue($this->cObj->data['pi_flexform'], 'DISPLAY', 'general');

        $content = $this->$func();
```

In one extension, it will call function according to the value in `DISPLAY` field, if I want to find which page has setting `DISPLAY=view`, instead to go to `admin->page->plugin options->display` to check, is there any fast way that I can find out the right page which has setting `DISPLAY=view`? I have many pages in the site, it is time consuming if check page by page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only other way is to check in the database. There is a `pi_flexform` field in `tt_content` which contains the xml of the flexforms. You can search in that field in a tool like phpmyadmin or something similar.